# Why does InputStreamReader throw a NPE when reading from a jar?

Tags: java, jar, stream, io, inputstream

I'm trying to iterate over the class files in a known directory using streams. The ultimate goal is to obtain the class names for all classes that exist in a particular package, then load the classes at runtime and use reflection to obtain the names & values of all the static constants. This works when I run the program from source on my machine, but when I run it as a jar the `BufferedReader` throws a NPE from both `ready()` and `readLine()`. Here's the code (with error handling & best practices omitted for brevity):

```
private void printClassNamesInPackage(final String strPackage) throws Exception {
    // The returned implementation of InputStream seems to be at fault
    final InputStream       packageStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( strPackage );
    final InputStreamReader streamReader  = new InputStreamReader( packageStream );
    final BufferedReader    reader        = new BufferedReader( streamReader );
    // Throws NPE from inside ready() - SEE STACKTRACE BELOW
    // reader.ready()
    String strLine;
    // Throws NPE from inside readLine() -  SEE STACKTRACE BELOW
    while ( null != (strLine = reader.readLine()) ) {
        System.out.println( strLine );
    }
}
```

*The stacktrace from `reader.ready()`*:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.available(FilterInputStream.java:142)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.inReady(StreamDecoder.java:343)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implReady(StreamDecoder.java:351)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.ready(StreamDecoder.java:165)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.ready(InputStreamReader.java:178)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.ready(BufferedReader.java:436)
```

*The stacktrace from `reader.readLine()`*:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
```

Stepping through the execution reveals the following `InputStream` implementations:

- From source: `java.io.ByteArrayInputStream`
- From jar: `sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream`

Looking further into `JarURLInputStream` I find that the inherited (from `FilterInputStream`) field `InputStream in` is `null`, which leads to the resulting NPE.

Unfortunately, that's as deep as I was able to get in the debugger.

Any ideas on how to properly do this? What am I missing or doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: To recap, you're trying to get an `InputStream` of a folder instead of a file, right?

Comment: Is it possible "getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( strPackage );" is returning null?

Comment: @BalusC: Yes. The original implementation simply created a `new File` for the `strPackage` directory then used `listFiles()` to obtain the classes within. I'm refactoring it to use streams instead of `File` objects so we can support execution from a jar.

Comment: @JustinKSU: No, as you can see I provided the runtime implementations returned by `getResourceAsStream`.

Comment: Folders don't return an `InputStream` with some list of all files or something. Use `JarInputStream` to extract the JAR programmatically. http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0513.html

Comment: @BalusC: This looks like an answer - could you please write it as one and include the linked code?

Comment: OK, I reposted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folders don't return an `InputStream` with some list of all files or something. Use [`JarInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html) to extract the JAR programmatically. You can find an example [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0513.html). For reference, here's a slight modified extract of relevance:

```
public static List<String> getClassNamesInPackage(String jarName, String packageName) throws IOException {
    JarInputStream jarFile = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(jarName));
    packageName = packageName.replace(".", "/");
    List<String> classes = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        for (JarEntry jarEntry; (jarEntry = jarFile.getNextJarEntry()) != null;) {
            if ((jarEntry.getName().startsWith(packageName)) && (jarEntry.getName().endsWith(".class"))) {
                classes.add(jarEntry.getName().replace("/", "."));
            }
        }
    } finally {
        jarFile.close();
    }

    return classes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I wasn't aware of the `JarInputStream` class. This might work great, but I'm concerned with the need of the jar name - why is there no solution that keeps the fact that I'm loading from a jar versus the local file system transparent? I haven't given this a shot yet, but I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: It does exist but not the way you want it. You can only refer to items on the classpath if you know them by name. The classloader then handles the loading transparently: it might load from a file, a JAR, a network socket, etc. There is no generic method to list those items.